# How to find path of loader DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to read binary of loader DLL of my DLL. But there is an exe and 2 DLL that I use first one (X DLL) for loadind second one (Y DLL). When I load Y dll from X DLL via exe, `GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szEXEPath, 2048);` function give me just exe path. I want to get X DLL path. I could use  `GetModuleFileNameA("X DLL Name", szEXEPath, 2048);` but I dont know name of X DLL.

When I read MSDN help for `GetModuleFileName` I saw the description that in below about first parameter of function.

> A handle to the loaded module whose path is being requested. If this
>   parameter is `NULL`, `GetModuleFileName` retrieves the path of the
>   executable file of the current process.

I dont want to get path of executable, I just want to determine which DLL load my current DLL. Is there a way to find loader path DLL?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do this. A strack trace maybe?

Comment: I understand this to mean you want the name of the "parent" dll, the one that loads your dll (see below). With some assistance it is not too hard.

Comment: Arrange for X to call a function in Y and to provide the information

Comment: @DavidHeffernan X is already calling some functions in Y. But I could not get path or name of X in Y.

Comment: Only because you didn't do what I said. Y needs to export a function that accepts the information that it needs. Then X calls that function passing that information.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But I dont want to get this information with  parameter form X to Y. I have to get this info from Y. Because parameter is not 100% reliable.

Comment: Passing parameters is indeed reliable. Are aware that there is no concept of loading DLL?

Comment: why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: What did you intend to do with this information anyway?  I can think of one or two vaguely legitimate use cases, but they all fall over if more than one DLL with a dependency on your DLL is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

To get the "parent" dll's name, you can create a function as part of the API that is required to be called, that passes in the `HMODULE` handle of the parent dll.

Creating the `get_current_module_handle()` function below as `inline` and wrapping it up into a macro of some sort would simplify the process for the client code.

```
//... control header
inline HMODULE get_current_module_handle() {/*...*/}
#define PARENT_MODULE get_current_module_handle()
void SetControlParent(HMODULE parent);
//... client code to initialise the "parent"
SetControlParent(PARENT_MODULE);
```

To get the dll name (in the child), you can use a combination of the [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx) and `GetModuleHandleEx` functions. The trick is in the [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200(v=vs.85).aspx) function that allows for the module handle to be obtain via a pointer to a function (i.e. a function in the dll); particularly the use of the flag `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS`.

What follows is a snippet from some code that should do the trick;

```
HMODULE get_current_module_handle()
{
    HMODULE moduleHandle = NULL;
    if (!::GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT,
        (LPCTSTR)get_current_module_handle, &moduleHandle))
        throw std::runtime_error("unable to get the module handle");
    return moduleHandle;
}

std::basic_string<TCHAR> get_module_name(HMODULE moduleHandle)
{
    std::vector<TCHAR> filename(2048, _T('?')); // allocate some space
    DWORD filenameLength = ::GetModuleFileNameEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), moduleHandle, &filename.front(), filename.size());
    if (filenameLength && filenameLength < filename.size()) {
        return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(&filename.front(), filenameLength);
    }
    return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(_T("unknown"));
}

//...

std::basic_string<TCHAR> dllname = get_module_name(get_current_module_handle()); // current dll
std::basic_string<TCHAR> parentdllname = get_module_name(parentHModule); // for "parent" dll
```

*Note*, a simplified version is reproduced above (based on the 2048 length in the OP). A recursive implementation to account for long file name is also presented (check the edits).

The `dllname` will be the fully qualified path of the module, hence to get the base file name, functions such as [`_splitpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx). Alternatively, you can use [`GetModuleBaseName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196(v=vs.85).aspx) directly in the code above.

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> get_module_name(HMODULE moduleHandle)
{
    std::vector<TCHAR> filename(MAX_PATH, _T('?')); // MAX_PATH is 260
    DWORD filenameLength = ::GetModuleBaseName(::GetCurrentProcess(), moduleHandle, &filename.front(), filename.size());
    if (filenameLength && filenameLength < filename.size()) {
        return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(&filename.front(), filenameLength);
    }
    return std::basic_string<TCHAR>(_T("unknown"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dllpath function to define its own path and pass it as a paramater to the linked one.

Comment: If I understand your answer, you are saying "send name of X DLL or path like a parameter". Actually I dont want to point out path or name of X DLL from the outside. Because I will not develop it and it is important for my controls. If developer send same path or name all time, I cannot check the real loader DLL.

Comment: @ceyun: if the person using your DLL doesn't follow the rules, then the  DLL won't work properly, but that's their fault, not yours.  It would probably be sensible to ask for a module handle (as per Niall's answer) rather than a string, because that's less work for the developer, but you *must* get the information from the caller - there's no other way to do it,  since Windows does not track the information you're asking for.

Comment: But if I see the modules in visualstudio for Y DLL, its show me the X DLL in it. I think we can get this information from where windows kept this .

Comment: @ceyun Suppose that I load DLL A. Now A has dependencies on B and C.  And B and C both depend on D. So the loader processes all this and loads B, C and D. Which DLL loaded D?

Comment: @ceyun Does that module dialog maintain a tree, rooted at the executable module, with each module appearing exactly once? Perhaps you could show a screenshot so we could have some idea of what you are actually referring to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think, if you call any D function from B, it should be B but when I check the function result; right answer is A. It will give me the name of A DLL

Comment: Why should it be B? Why do you prefer B to C? I posit that you don't understand how module dependencies are implemented. If you would tell us what the actual problem is we could perhaps point you at the right solution. But at the moment you've decided on a solution that is ill-defined.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It could be C too as you said. I have just choosen an option. I think, problem is crystal clear. I am looking for just X DLL path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105140/discussion-between-ceyun-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: No the problem is not at all clear. But you won't listen to advice, so it's a waste of everyone's time to continue.